# Override partial_update (PATCH DJANGO)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, patch

I have a simple `PATCH` method, where I sent a bunch of paramaters to my object `Foo`, including a parameter `new_bar`. I want to first patch all the other fields, and then append `new_bar` to the current obejcts `bar` data.

I'm having issues where Django refuses to accept my override of partial route (error:

`response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) TypeError: decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given))`

How can I override my PATCH method to accept this paramater `bar` on my object food, and append it. I am sending in the new data as key `new_bar` to not confuse Django and get caught in the initial patch step:

```
   @detail_route
   def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid()        
    instance = serializer.save()

    bar = self.request.POST.get('new_bar', None)
    if bar:
        if len(instance.bar) == 0:
            instance.bar = bar
        else:
            # Append
            bar = json.loads(bar)
            old_bar = json.loads(instance.bar)
            instance.bar = json.dumps(oldbar)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `@detail_route` decorator.  DRF knows that the `.partial_update` method is for `PATCH`.